# Why is this parse error here Parse error: syntax error, unexpected identifier "edit", expecting "," or ";"?

Tags: php, html

```
  <td>{$row['date']}</td>
          <td><a href="edit.php?applicationid=<?php echo $data['applicationid']; ?>">Edit</a></td>

        </tr>";
```

In 2nd line I am getting this error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected identifier "edit", expecting "," or ";"

Comment: Is that part of a string? You don't use `<?php` in strings, you just put the variable, like you did with `$row['date']`

Comment: The double quote in `href="edit` is ending your string. Either change that to a single quote or escape it with backslash.

Comment: It is not working with single quote Parse error: syntax error, unexpected string content "", expecting "-" or identifier or variable or number in C:\xampp\htdocs\users\admin.php on line 98

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be part of a string literal, and you're ending the listeral with the `"` in `href="`. You need to escape that or use single quotes.

Also, you don't use `<?php echo $variable ?>` to embed a variable in a string, you use `{$variable}`, like yo udid with `$row['date']`

```
echo "<td>{$row['date']}</td>
          <td><a href='edit.php?applicationid={$data['applicationid']}'>Edit</a></td>

        </tr>";
```